# Updating getDerivedStateFromProps to functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am updating old react components, and was using `getDerivedStateFromProps`, and i'd like to update the class to a functional component, but I'm not sure what to do with this particular function.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  const oldQuestionsOn = state.questionsOn || {};
  const blankQuestionsOn = fromPairs(
     props.questions.map(({ type, on }) => [type, !!on])
  );
  const questionsOn = { ...blankQuestionsOn, ...oldQuestionsOn };
  return { questionsOn };
}
```

Do I use `useEffect` as the alternative? If so, how do I get `state` since its not the state of the component it's in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to setState that will receive the latest value as it's parameter. You could most likely implement this without the function, just using questions instead of cur and calling setQuestions instead of a return.
if this codes doesn't run, it's because props.questions didn't change it's reference, you can fix it by using `.slice()` when setting the new questions. If this code runs too often and is causing you some performance problems, you can fix it by memoizing the questions array, search for `useMemo` hook;

```
useEffect(() => {
  setQuestions((cur) => {
    const oldQuestionsOn = cur || {};
    const blankQuestionsOn = fromPairs(props.questions.map(({type, on}) => [type, Boolean(on)]);
    return { ...blankQuestionsOn, ...oldQuestionsOn };
  })
}, [props.questions])
```